# Execute check manually after dpkg-buildpackage DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck

Tags: debian, dpkg-buildpackage

I am running dpkg-buildpackage with the environment variable DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS set to nocheck. This compiles but skips the testing.
With which command can I execute the checking manually after dpkg-buildpackage has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all defined in `debian/rules` You should probably look for an upstream tests or for the content of `debian/tests` if present.

So basically the `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` is just an environment variable and it's up to the maintainer of d/rules how to handle it.
dpkg-buildpackage doesn't care about it, it is just the makefile - `debian/rules` which has some code checking for this var.

For example:

```
override_dh_auto_test:
    ifeq (,$(filter nocheck,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
    dh_auto_test --no-parallel
endif
```

The official docs:
https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules-options

Comment: Could you point out the command I should run that makes as few assumptions as the high-level debuild command?
I can see something like this happening "cd build-debian && make test" with some options in dpkg-buildpackage.

Comment: do you mean dh_auto_test? see it's man page for the details.